# How to implement bulk updateOne with mongodb in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, bulkupdate

I'm trying to implement bulk update for a list of objects. But I'm getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name bookingId
at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeName(AbstractBsonWriter.java:532)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:114)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:60)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:398)
at com.mongodb.operation.BulkWriteBatch$WriteRequestEncoder.encode(BulkWriteBatch.java:377)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:63)
at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.encode(BsonDocumentWrapperCodec.java:29)
```

The implementation for the updates are as follows:

```
public void _deleteAll( ArrayList<T> pojos ) {
    Assert.notNull( pojos, "Entity must not be null!" );
    BulkOperations ops = mongoTemplate.bulkOps( BulkOperations.BulkMode.ORDERED, className, collectionName );


    for ( T pojo : pojos ) {
        System.out.println( ( ( BaseEntity ) pojo ).get_id() );
        ( ( BaseEntity ) pojo ).setIsDeleted( true );
        Query query = new Query( Criteria.where( "_id" ).is( ( ( BaseEntity ) pojo ).get_id() ) );
        Document document = Document.parse( pojo.toString() ); //toString() returns JSON string
        Update update = Update.fromDocument( document );
        ops.updateOne( query, update );
    }
    ops.execute();
}
```

Second approach with `WriteModel`

```
public void _deleteAll( ArrayList<T> pojos ) {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection( collectionName );
    List<WriteModel<Document>> writes = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( T pojo : pojos ) {
        ( ( BaseEntity ) pojo ).setIsDeleted( true );
        writes.add(
            new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
                new Document().append( "_id", ( ( BaseEntity ) pojo ).get_id() ), Document.parse( pojo.toString() )
            )
        );
    }
    collection.bulkWrite( writes );
}
```

The JSON data is similar to this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d81d87ac290c518433e66d9"),
    "bookingId" : 100344391,
    "body" : "{\"title\”:\"Some title\”,\”booking_room_id\":null,\”message\”:\"some message\”}",
    “nestedObject" : {
        “someKey" : “some value"
    },
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-09-18T07:10:50.067Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-09-18T07:28:16.062Z"),
    "isDeleted" : false,
    "_class" : "com.test.mongo_test.entity.mongo.SomePojo"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/bulk-writes/). Basically what I had to do was add the query command `$set` in the document.

```
writes.add(
    new UpdateOneModel<>(
        new Document( "_id", new ObjectId( id ) ),
        new Document( "$set", Document.parse( pojo.toString() ) )
    )
);
```